# How to validate the transfer protocol

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js application and I would like to validate if the transport protocol is websocket, xhr-polling, flashsocket and etc Is it possible and how can I do it?

If I set:

```
io.set('transports', [ 'websocket', 'flashsocket','xhr-polling']);
```

will this code allow only these transport protocols and if it's true, how can I handle if the thansport protocol is other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. `Yes`, It'll allow only these transport protocols to connect.
2. In default case, if you access the server with other unspecified protocol. You'll get `connection error` or `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

PS. I `don't know` if you can or cannot `catch` other transport protocol errors.